# Store serialization files in java library

Tags: java, file, api, serialization

I'm developing a tiny data mining java library that works on top
of WEKA library.

Now and then I have the need in the code to write and read serialization files,
where is the correct place to store them ?

Should I use current directory or are there better options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the serialized files wherever you like, the "best" option depends on how the files are being used and what the layout of your filesystem is.

How long will you need to store the serialized files for?

- **A few minutes?**  Consider writing them to a /tmp directory
- **A few days/weeks?**  Consider writing them to a /data folder that could be placed somewhere logically in your application's file system
- **Months/years?** At this point you probably want to be persisting to a database with some sort of redundancy.  If you do decide to stick with a basic file system, organize the files into subfolders such as /data/2015/.

Again, there is not "best" or "preferred" option.  Depends on the data you are storing and what type of application it is.  But these are some basic guidelines that I typically go by.